# Calculating resistance in this circuit

Tags: electrical-resistance

I can't seem to figure out how my teacher got to this. This is the circuit I am supposed to calculate resistance for (my teachers calculations are at the bottom of the picture):

[image: The circuit]

When I try to calculate the resistance, I basically just use the two rules for parallel and series.
First I add up the resistance from the resistors in the corner (red color) - that I add up the resistance of the resistor that is in parallel with it (green color). These three I then substitute for a resistor containing 2R resistance (blue color) - This one is in series with the bottom right resistor - that makes it a 4R resistor (purple color) - Purple resistor is in parallel with the middle 4R resistor - that makes a 2R resistor (grey color), which is in parallel with the single R resistors - these three make up to a resistor with 4R resistance (pink color) and that is finally in parallel with the 4R resistor on the left - which leaves me with the total resistance of the circuit of 2R.

[image]

I can't seem to figure out, how I am supposed to get to 5R - as seen in the first picture. Am I doing something wrong here? Or my teacher just wrongly copy pasted something and it's a mistake. Thank you for your advice!

Comment: I think you are right and the teacher is wrong.

Comment: It looks like 2R to me, We'll see if someone points out a mistake that we are making.

Comment: Thank you guys for your responses! I think we can all agree on the result being 2R. I appreciate your time, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your teacher's answer is wrong.  You can tell it is wrong since the 4R resistor on the left is shunted by the combination of the resistors connected to it on the right; this combination is in parallel with the 4R resistor on the left, so no matter their total effective resistance they will lower the total resistance of the circuit below 4R.  I calculate the effective resistance of the resistors on the right connected in parallel to the 4R resistor on the left as 4R; so, the effective circuit is 4R in parallel with 4R for a total effective resistance or 2R as you say.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm revising for an exam that I take tomorrow and his materials don't really help me and I was confused. Thank you for clarifying! Appreciate it.

Comment: You are welcome:)

Answer (score 0):

The given [electrical circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_network) consists of 3 [series circuits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_and_parallel_circuits#Series_circuits) and 3 [parallel circuits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_and_parallel_circuits#Parallel_circuits). The resistance in the first series circuit is 2R + 2R = 4R. The resistance in the first parallel circuit is 1/(1/4R + 1/4R) = 2R. The resistance in the second series circuit is again 2R + 2R = 4R. The resistance in the second parallel resistance is again 1/(1/4R + 1/4R) = 2R. Now, the resistance in the third series circuit is R + 2R + R = 4R. The final parallel circuit has a resistance of 1/(1/4R + 1/4R) = 2R.